# What are the TypeScript project build configuration options?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

When I create a new "HTMLWeb App" project, I get a .csproj with a few default options in the project XML for Typescript. Where can I find a list of all possible TypeScript build options?

Searching for the names of the 3 options currently in my project, such as "TypeScriptIncludeComments", returned no results on Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the list of options in the `.targets` file that shipped with the TypeScript installation. Here is the full list of options with the command line argument that gets actually sent to "tsc.exe" (the TypeScript compiler)

- TypeScriptIncludeComments .....  `--comments`
- TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations .....  `--declaration`
- TypeScriptModuleKind ..... `--module $(TypeScriptModuleKind)`
- TypeScriptIncludeDefaultLib .....  `--nolib`
- TypeScriptOutFile .....  `--out $(TypeScriptOutFile)`
- TypeScriptSourceMap .....  `--sourcemap`
- TypeScriptTarget .....  `--target $(TypeScriptTarget)`
- TypeScriptAdditionalFlags .....  `$(TypeScriptAdditionalFlags)`

Comment: would be good to know what they do rather than just listing their names

Answer (score 4):

Update on Guptas's answer for Visual Studio 2015 RC. The Microsoft.TypeScript.targets file is now in c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript.

- TypeScriptRemoveComments ..... `--removeComments`
- TypeScriptNoImplicitAny ..... `--noImplicitAny`
- TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations ..... `--declaration`
- TypeScriptModuleKind ..... `--module "$(TypeScriptModuleKind)"`
- TypeScriptOutFile ..... `--out "$(TypeScriptOutFile)"`
- TypeScriptOutDir ..... `--outDir "$(TypeScriptOutDir)"`
- TypeScriptSourceMap ..... `--sourcemap`
- TypeScriptTarget ..... `--target $(TypeScriptTarget)`
- TypeScriptNoResolve ..... `--noResolve`
- TypeScriptAdditionalFlags ..... `$(TypeScriptAdditionalFlags)`
- TypeScriptMapRoot ..... `--mapRoot "$(TypeScriptMapRoot)"`
- TypeScriptSourceRoot ..... `--sourceRoot "$(TypeScriptSourceRoot)"`
- TypeScriptCodePage ..... `--codepage $(TypeScriptCodePage)`
- TypeScriptCharset ..... `--charset $(TypeScriptCharset)`
- TypeScriptEmitBOM ..... `--emitBOM`
- TypeScriptNoLib ..... `--noLib`
- TypeScriptPreserveConstEnums ..... `--preserveConstEnums`
- TypeScriptSuppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors ..... `--suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to change any Typescript build options is with [Web Extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6). I'd highly recommend it if you do any kind of web work with Visual Studio.

Comment: This only works with VS 2012. If you have VS 2010 you need to manually edit the CSPROJ file.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I forgot that the Typescript plugin even works with VS2010.