# Visual Studio 2017 can't change project.csproj's <TypescriptModuleKind> for typescript transpiling

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, module, tsc

This comes out of my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48436147/1019307.

I need to change the module kind that the transpiler VS uses to be `AMD`. It defaults to `commonjs` even when the `<TypescriptModuleKind>` is changed in the `project.csproj`'s  from `commonjs` to be `AMD`.

To see the problem:

1. Add the typescript addons - Typescript Tools, Typescript Build and Rich Newman's Typescript HTML Application Template.
2. Create new project using the template
3. Observe the `project.csproj` contains `<TypescriptModuleKind>commonjs</TypescriptModuleKind>` and leave it like that
4. Start server.  It starts fine and the application can be seen running (with no error messages in the developers console)
5. Open the `app.js` file and observe that it starts with:

   ```
   "use strict";      
   var Greeter = /** @class */ (function () {
       function Greeter(element) {
   ```
6. Open `app.ts` and prefix with `export` to make it `export class Greeter {`
7. refresh the page and observe the error `exports is undefined` in the developer console
8. Open the `app.js` file and observe it now says the following:

   ```
   "use strict";
   Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
   var Greeter = /** @class */ (function () {
   ```
9. Create a `tsconfig.json` by running `tsc --init`
10. Observe that it contains `"module": "commonjs"`
11. Run `tsc` to transpile the ts files
12. Observe the `app.js` file is still as above (and would cause the `exports is not defined` error)
13. Change the `tsconfig.json` file so that it contains `"module": "amd"`
14. Run `tsc` to transpile the ts files
15. Open the `app.js` file and observe it now says the following:

    ```
      define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
          "use strict";
          Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
          var Greeter = /** @class */ (function () {
    ```
16. Follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/48436147/1019307 to setup to use `requirejs` :-)
17. Refresh and observe it works in the browser and no errors are shown
18. Move the `tsconfig.json` out of the way by renaming eg to `xxxxtsconfigxx.xxjson`
19. Stop the server; modify the `app.ts` file to make it dirty; restart the server
20. Observe the `exports is not defined` error has returned
21. If you like, rename the file as `tsconfig.json` and repeat the last step and observe the error still exists.  This confirms that VS does not use the local `tsconfig.json` for configuration.
22. Modify the `project.csproj` to contain `<TypescriptModuleKind>amd</TypescriptModuleKind>`
23. Stop the server; modify the `app.ts` file to make it dirty; restart the server
24. Observe the `exports is not defined` error has returned

Thus proving that VS does not honor the `tsconfig.json` file and seems to ignore its `TypescriptModuleKind` configuration value.

[What are the TypeScript project build configuration options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864584/what-are-the-typescript-project-build-configuration-options#15864631) seems to say how VS uses tsc.  I ran using the `--module` switch and it worked correctly (eg. `tsc --module commonjs [app.ts]` and `tsc --module amd [app.ts]`).  With `[app.ts]` being required if the `tsconfig.json` file doesn't exist.  Thus it seems that VS is ignoring the `TypescriptModuleKind` setting or not applying it in the way that it should.

So what's the deal here.  Is there any way to make it either use the `tsconfig.json` file or honor its `TypescriptModuleKind` setting?

Comment: I know that in VS2015, if there's a tsconfig.json inside a project folder, then the visual studio typescript configuration is ignored. When you view the project settings there's a big message that will tell you that (it's possible you have to close VS and re-open it to make sure it's recognising the tsconfig.json). So maybe you need to omit any TypeScript settings from the .csproj file, make sure they're set correctly in the tsconfig.json then close and re-open VS for good measure?

Comment: Thanks Chris.  You might be correct but I didn't test.  As when I following up after reading your question I found in the Project's Properties a `Typescript Build` (side) tab and there is a dropdown labeled `Module System` which I set to 'AMD'.  And this worked!  Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

In the Project's Properties there is a `Typescript Build` (side) tab and there is a dropdown labeled `Module System` which I set to 'AMD'.  And this worked!  Awesome.

[image: Visual Studio's Project Properties and Typescript build and modules]

In a comment @Chris Halcrow suggested that if you take out the Typescript configurations from the project file then VS may use the configuration from the `tsconfig.json`.  I didn't try it but definitely worth a try for the case where you need more options than what VS supplies.

---

I just found https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24584/cant-compile-the-ts-files-on-vs2017-node-modules-n.html, which has some useful information on how VS deals with typescript.

I also realised that @ChrisHalcrow was correct when he said "if there's a tsconfig.json inside a project folder then the VS TS Config is ignored".  I hadn't forced VS to recognise the `tsconfig.json` file.  Once I added it again, it was seen.  I forgot that VS needs to have things 'add'ed (source files, config files, ..).  I'm used to Eclipe and IDEA seeing the changes and asking or just doing.

Even more awesome!

[image: Visual Studio's Project Properties and Typescript build and modules disabled]